# Выборка в mySQL по нескольким параметрам

Tags: mysql, сортировка

Голову сломал, поэтому, прошу помощи.
Суть вопроса: есть таблица table, в которой хранятся объявления. Вот такая структура:

```
id | author_id | rubric_id | published | остальное не важно
```

Например, мне нужно вывести массив из 10 объявлений, в таком порядке:
1) Сначала объявления с author_id=XXX, если они есть
2) Если их нет, или их набралось менее, чем 10, то дополнить массив объявлениями с rubric_id=YYY
3) Если массив до сих пор не наполнился 10-ю элементами, то добавить в него ещё несколько рандомных объявлений
4) И всё это отсортировать по дате published

Как правильно составить mySQL-запрос?

Уф))) Спасибо!!!

Comment: Что мешает сделать вам несколько запросов в зависимости от 1-го ответа если условие скажем `false` дополняем массив вторым запросом, если и оно `false` тогда третьим

Comment: сначала `order by author_id=XXX desc, rubric_id=YYY desc limit 10`, потом обернуть в еще один запрос и пересортировать так, как требуется

Comment: @RifmaMan Не надо ничего делать несколькими запросами, всегда лучше получать из БД ровно те данные, которые требуются

Comment: @Mike а как уставить условия в запрос где будет учитываться ответ запроса <10 или =10? т.к. от этого зависит последующее действие делать запросы по другим полям и формировать ли рандомные элементы к недостающим

Comment: @Mike покажите пожалуйста свое мастерство в деле ответив корректно на вопрос, а я заодно и поучусь мастерству mysql ;D

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
  from (
    select id, author_id, rubric_id, published
      from table
     order by author_id=XXX desc, rubric_id=YYY desc
     limit 10
   ) X
  order by published
```

Таков синтаксис для MySQL, так как в нем условие `author_id=XXX` возвращает *0* в случае если автор не равен XXX и *1* если равен. Таким образом при обратной сортировке в начале получаем всех авторов XXX, после них идут остальные авторы. Для совпавших значений первой колонки идет сортировка по второй, а следовательно для не совпавших авторов первыми получаем нужную рубрику.

P.S. для других СУБД сравнение может не давать числовые 0 и 1 и там потребуется писать более сложные конструкции вроде `order by case author_id when XXX then 1 else 0 end desc, ...`

Comment: Наверное, надо, с учётом *ещё несколько рандомных объявлений* в выражение сортировки добавить в конце `, RAND()`. А то этот дополнительный остаток может быть совсем даже не случайным. PS. Прощай, производительность...

Comment: @Akina Как раз с учетом производительности я решил не добавлять rand, пока не уточнят насколько случайными они должны быть :)

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from (
select * from table where author_id=XXX
union 
select * from table where rubric_id=YYY
union
select * from table where author_id <> XXX and rubric_id <> YYY) 
order by published 
limit 10
```

Comment: не прокатит. внешний order мгновенно собьет порядок выборки внутренних union, отсортирует вообще все строки таблицы и только после этого будет применен лимит

Comment: подтверждаю - не прокатило)))